# Correct way Entity framework master-detail insert record code for inserting child

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and tying to learn correct way of updating data.

Customer

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCustomId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableListSource<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Contact

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactMobile { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Form1

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context = new winproContext();
        var query = _context.Customers;
        this.customerBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }


    private void customerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            _context.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 
    }

    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var customer = new Customer { CustomerName = "test" };
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        // How to add contact details ?
        // How to add get value from datagridView column 
    }
```

How to add contact details ?

How to add get value from datagridView column ?

Is that code ok or can someone suggest better way of doing this.

Where/how to remove insert code from forms into separate class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var customer = new Customer { CustomerName = "test" };
    _context.Customers.Add(customer);
    var newContact = new Contact();   

    customer.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();// it needs becorse your collection is null 


    customer.Contacts.Add(newContact);  //just add new child to collection of parent
    _context.Customers.Add(customer);
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

the better way is to make collection initialization inside of entity object

```
public partial class Customer
{
public Customer()
{
    this.Contacts = new ObservableListSource<Contact>();
}

public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public int CustomerCustomId { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
protected ObservableListSource<Contact> _Contacts;
public virtual ObservableListSource<Contact> Contacts 
{ 
  get{            

    if( _Contacts==null) _Contacts= new ObservableListSource<Contact>();            
      return _Contacts;
      } 
    set{
         _Contacts=value;
       } 
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I usualy use ObservableCollection. It standart practice

Comment: Sure write that type as is in your class. I just want to show that it needs to make sure that you collection is not null at the moment when you goin to Add something to it. It's not the problem when EntityFramework loading data from db and set entire collection. But it  became to be a problem if you try to insert new values in new (just created) object to it in you code

Comment: Thank you for acception. If everything is fine please delete your comments about mistakes. It not interesting for community i think